# Open HTML file without .html?

Tags: .htaccess

I use webspace and have some html files on the webspace. For example the XY.html file.

When I call up domain.com/xy a 404 comes up. I always have to enter domain.com/xy.html.

Would you like to set that all .html files can also be called without .html?

Current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I've already tried the following, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Your `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` matches first on every request…

Comment: Should I delete this line?

Comment: Maybe not if you want to keep executing PHP this way. You need to define your rules more clearly. Any non-existing URL is currently handled by index.php. Those HTML files fall under that rule. How should they be distinguished? If `$1.html` *exists* it should be handled by `$1.html`, else index.php…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
#rewrite non-existent requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```